# Extract only file_path from SAS variable

Tags: sql, unix, sas, sas-macro

I'm looking to extract just the directory path from a File_Path variable, excluding the file name in SAS. Can someone assist with this

```
/start_file_pth/data/sg/prod5/file_path/dataset1.sas7bdat.gz
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/sg/prod5/location/dataset2.sas7bdat
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/hk/prod89/test/dataset3.sas7bdat.gz
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/testing/hk/prod5/dataset4.sas7bdat
```

Required Output

```
/start_file_pth/data/sg/prod5/file_path/ 
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/sg/prod5/location/ 
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/hk/prod89/test/ 
/start_file_pth/data/lrstr/testing/hk/prod5/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data Solution;
    loc2 = '/sasgdcube/random/test/i/m/testing/nofile.sasgdtest';
  Directory_Path = substr(loc2, 1, length(loc2) - length(scan(loc2, -1, "/")))  ;
run;
```

Comment: You can also use `findc(loc2,'/','b')` as the 3rd argument of `substr()`.

Comment: Why ask the question if you were posting your own solution that only works for one line at a time?

Answer (score 0):

If you store all your fully qualified filenames into a space separated list, here is a macro that will put all the file paths into a table called fqpath.
With the options nonotes, it will turn off proc sql confirmations and timings, which gives you a copy/paste-able text list in the log.

It's also robust enough to take an os path separator for windows/unix.

The code takes a list of filenames, counts the instances of path separators, then removes the substrings after the last separator.

```
    %let filenames=/start_file_pth/data/sg/prod5/file_path/dataset1.sas7bdat.gz /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/sg/prod5/location/dataset2.sas7bdat /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/hk/prod89/test/dataset3.sas7bdat.gz /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/testing/hk/prod5/dataset4.sas7bdat;
    
    %macro getallfilepaths(filenamelist, pathseperator);
    options nonotes;
        %let num= %QSYSFUNC(countw(&filenamelist., ' '));
        proc sql noprint; create table listoffilepaths(fqpath char(1024)); quit;
        %do i = 1 %to &num.;
            %let colname = %sysfunc(scan(&filenamelist., &i., ' '));
            %let countslash = %sysfunc(countc(&colname.,%str(&pathseperator.)));
            %let lastsepposition = %eval(%length(&colname.) - %length(%scan(&colname., &countslash., "&pathseperator.")));
            %let cleaned_string = %substr(&colname., 1, &lastsepposition.);
            %put &cleaned_string.;
            proc sql; insert into listoffilepaths(fqpath)  values("&cleaned_string."); quit;
        %end;
    %mend;
    
    %getallfilepaths(&filenames., /);
```

Produces:

| fqpath |
| --- |
| /start_file_pth/data/sg/prod5/file_path/ |
| /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/sg/prod5/location/ |
| /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/hk/prod89/test/ |
| /start_file_pth/data/lrstr/testing/hk/prod5/ |